# iOS: how to get access viewController's methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a trouble.
There is viewConntroller and an object inside this viewController. This object tries to get information via NSURLConnection later it has to notify viewController to run method. If i try to create object of viewController inside I catch problem: new viewController makes the same thing that first one do, so new viewController makes NSURLConnection, creates third viewController and so on.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Please give a better explanation.

Comment: Also, this has **absolutely nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.**

Comment: @trojanfor I need to access execly my viewController (without creating new one) to run method. From object inside this viewController (my models). My English i poor, and I think it's a problem to understand me, if it is, you may not help. I have been given good answers yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass reference to this object. But first create new property with assign attribute.

```
//property in your class
@property(nonatomic, assign) id myViewController;

//set reference to your UIViewController
[myClassInstance setMyViewController: self]; //self is MyViewController instance

//call UIViewController's method from your class
MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)self.myViewController;
[controller myMethodInUIViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing on a reference of the viewController to the object you´re making inside that viewController?

So something along the lines of:

```
Object *obj = [[Object alloc]init];
obj.viewController = self;
```

Obviously, you'd have to create an attribute to hold the viewController on the object class.

Then, when you need to call methods on the viewController, you could use:

```
[self.viewController performSelector:@selector(methodName:)];
```